# Need help choosing languague for this project

Tags: php, windows

first of all, sorry for bad english. Please correct me if I write something wrong!

I'm a "noob" in the programing scene, so I need some help. I want to help my mom to automate a process at her bussines. The core thing I need to do are this:

I need to extract info from a webpage (it's an php webpage), and compare the products that arrive with the one's displayed in the webpage. I want to do that scanning the bar codes of the products (I've a database of all the products barcodes). Then I need to save the comparission in a file just to make sure that everything is ok. I want to know wich languague is better for my case. (Then I will try to do it, fail, learn from my mistakes and then have some "stable" program to do this)

TL;DR: I recive products, I check if everything arrived in a website. I want to do that using bar codes and "automate" the process. I want to know wich languague is better for my case.

Thank you!!

Comment: You'll never get a straight answer for "which language is best" - it all comes down to personal taste and experience. SO is aimed at asking questions with specific answers, not opinions.

Comment: the "best" language is always the one you can use the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out in the coments, there is not best language, you need to chose the one that fits you.

But let me give you some recommendations on what might work.

You said that the site is already in PHP, that's the backend language. You should keep using it since a part of the site is already built with it. Other options are JavaScript using NodeJS, Python, Java, Ruby.

You can do almost everything you need in the backend (server side) using PHP, but some things might be better to solve them in the client side (front end) using JavaScript, is the default language that runs on the browsers.

Usually you use the backend language to serve pages, interact with a database, send data to the client. And the front end (JavaScript) to add dynamic functionality to your website.

Web apps used to depend a lot on the backend, reloading the page for every action, sending a lot of information back and forth.

The modern aproach to build web apps (like yours) is a bit more dependant on JavaScript. You load the page once and then just do AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) requests to the server asking just for the information you need and showing it dynamicly with out reloading and having to load the HTML/CSS all over again. Many frameworks like [Angular](http://angularjs.org/), [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) (with its whole ecosystem), help you a lot with it.

Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

EDIT: just to clirify, I answered with some recommendations and opinions because it is what the question asks for.

Comment: Thank you man! That was what I wanted. Sorry if I did something wrong! Thankss